# Fill Input Field with Dropdown Selection (PHP - AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i'm trying to fill some fields from database using a selected dropdown. I did it with ajax but aparently my code doesn't work because the fields keep empty. Can you help me out please?

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2" for="boxListaRetiro">Retiro:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
            <select class="form-control" id="boxListaRetiro" name="boxListaRetiro">
                <option>Selecciona Retiro</option>
                <!-- This is filled with a function in javascript and its working just fine -->
                <!-- EXAMPLE ROW <option value="1"> $500 | 2017-04-08</option>-->
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2" for="motivo">Motivo:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="motivo" name="motivo" placeholder="Motivo del retiro" value="" disabled></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Anular</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

AJAX

```
//Ajax when second box change
$('#boxListaRetiro').on('change',function(){
    var idRetiro = $(this).val();
    if(idRetiro){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'PostData.php',
            data:'idRetiro='+idRetiro,
            success:function(html){
                var valores = JSON.parse(html);
                $('#motivo').html(valores[0].motivo);
            }
        }); 
});
```

PostData.php

```
if(isset($_POST["idRetiro"]) && !empty($_POST["idRetiro"])){
   //Get the Data
   $sql = "SELECT monto, motivo FROM retiro WHERE idRetiro = " . 
   $_POST['idRetiro'];
   $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
   $rowCount = $result->num_rows;
   $array = array();

   //Muestro el valor del monto
   if($rowCount > 0){
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
           $array[] = $row;
       }
       echo json_encode($array);
   }
```

Comment: I bet for _undefined_: $row.

Comment: add `console.log(html)` to your success callback and see what you get. Or check network-tab in devtools to see the return.

Comment: also you're trying to fill an `input` with html (another input!), which won't work. You'd have to replace the (inner) html of the surrounding `div`

Comment: `.html()` is like `.innerHTML`, sort of. Input Elements support `.val()` which is like `.value`. If the Element doesn't support `.innerHTML` then it won't take HTML inside it. Note that this is true for buttons and select options, as well as inputs of any kind.

Comment: i will try this in a moment and let you know guys. thank you

Comment: @Jeff Thank you for let me know that i can see in console.log() some things. with that, i just change the php code a little, now i trying to get an array and the console show me this --> [{"monto":"500","motivo":"Hola, soy el motivo"}] How i put the value of "motivo" in my field motivo?

Comment: @Jeff THANK YOU JEFF!! its working now. the console.log() has helped me a lot. thank you so much. how can i give you good reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('#monto').parent().html(html);
```

Comment: Hi !! i try this and showed me all the JSON array. Its a big step but i want just the field. I change the code a little. when you can take a look i will aprecciate

Comment: its working right now! i updated the code. Thank you for your time!!